# Is it bad practice to add "false or" or "true and" to conditionals?

Tags: programming-practices, language-agnostic, patterns-and-practices, conditions

Is it bad practice to add `false or ...` or `true and ...` for the sake of promoting code genericness and/or ease of use?

As in:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE TRUE
  AND IsEnabled
  AND SomeField = some_value
  AND SomeOtherField != some_value
```

in SQL or in javascript for example:

```
if (false
      || prop === 'category'
      || prop === 'subCategory'
      || prop === 'productLogisticGroup'
      || prop === 'productName'
      || prop === 'color'
      || prop === 'configuration'
)
```

This lets adding or removing conditions a little easier by removing the thinking process whether the condition is on the edge or not. Is this bad in someway?

Comment: Aside: I would change the second example to `if (set(...).contains(prop))`

Comment: Any code whose intention requires explanation about why you're doing it to someone reading or reviewing it the code seems undesirable to me.  You've mentioned that your intention is to make the code more generic and easier to use, but even with that explanation I have to say I still don't understand what the point is, and honestly can't see how it makes the code more generic or easier to use.   Maybe I'm just not smart enough to understand, but then it's often a good idea to assume your audience isn't very smart and keep in mind the Principle of least astonishment.

Comment: In fact, I'd say if your only reason for doing that is to communicate to other developers, then a far more direct and less cryptic way of doing that would be to add a comment which lays out your intention explicitly - for example `/* Add new conditions here */`

Comment: @BenCottrell It's just easier to (comment in / out) / add / remove the conditions thanks to them being kind of unattached to the other lines. Very much like ending a list with a `,`. It disattaches the positional requirement from it.

Comment: I would not recommend it. It always provokes a WTF by the next maintenance programmer.

Comment: I use this `false or` idiom *a lot*, precisely to keep the code more aligned. But it's super confusing for people who don't know it. In the SQL case, the more common approach would be to right-align the keywords.

Comment: For SQL alignment and debugging purposes it's also common to write `WHERE 1 = 1 ...`, `WHERE 1 = 0 ...` respectively.

Comment: We can also add 0 and multiply by 1.

Comment: I agree with sentiments that this is more idiomatic in SQL than it is in procedural code, perhaps because SQL is more likely to be used interactively or to be subject to ongoing minor tweaking (so the ability to easily paste or comment out lines can be useful). If the code is to be maintained by others, it probably deserves a brief comment "for visual alignment of code only".

Comment: Adding noop code like that for the sake of code alignment seems like a big code smell to me. I'd hate to see that in any code base I'm supporting.

Comment: Reminds me of languages that let you have extra commas. Sure it’s a wart. But so are “get” prefixes. Avoid it if you can. Use it when you can’t. Never jumble.

Answer (score 8):

There are some useful corner cases but your examples do not look particularly meaningful to me. I use it mostly for debugging, if I temporarily want to switch of a block or I want to force myself into some block. I also use it for continuous loops like thread methods where the break condition is not that simple or the break condition depends on an internal calculation rather than an external boolean. But then the true or false is actually significant. In your examples they are purely esthetic and are likely to raise some eye brows if someone else reads your code.

It won't hurt much though, if this is how you roll, more power to you.

Answer (score 3):

I think the compiler will usually remove it, so it's doing no harm. I don't think it's adding anything useful either though.

However, most of the time when I've seen this is when someone is building up a SQL query string at run time, and that is usually bad practice. It's easy to introduce bugs (or SQL injection vulnerabilities) and hard to test or debug.

FWIW, here's how I'd write your examples:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE IsEnabled
  AND SomeField = some_value
  AND SomeOtherField != some_value


switch (prop)
{
     case 'category';
     case 'subCategory';
     case 'productLogisticGroup';
     case 'productName';
     case 'color';
     case 'configuration';
         DoTheThing();
         Break;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're *writing* this code yourself, then no; I wouldn't recommend it.

However, if you're writing *another* piece of code that will *generate* this code, then it might be more acceptable.  An example of this might be a SQL Query builder that produces SQL based on the given User inputs.  Including the leading, fixed condition means that your code *only* has to add the "extra" bits, as supplied by the User.  Without the leading, fixed bit, you'd have to do [a *tiny* bit] more, to set up the syntax correctly.
(Actually, in your first example, you could probably drop the TRUE clause because, I suspect, the "IsEnabled" check will *always* be there and is just as boog a place to start the WHERE clause).

Answer (score 1):

I've seen one situation where you actually (kind of) need to add a true or false: In Swift, you can declare conditionals on the command line. But if you write

```
if condition {
    statement
}
```

and "condition" is a false constant, you get a warning that the code will never be executed. Which is useful because the developer might not be aware. Change it to

```
if false || condition {
    statement
}
```

the warning goes away. Apparently the compiler assumes because of the "false || " that you know what you are doing, and that you are aware that the statement might be dead code, and removes the warning. Clang does that in other situations, for example in C or C++

```
if (false) {
    statement;
}
```

gives a warning, but

```
if ((false)) {
    statement;
}
```

doesn't. So warnings are generated not just depending on the semantics of a statement, but also depending on how you write it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd tend to write

```
if (   prop === 'category'
    || prop === 'subCategory'
    || prop === 'productLogisticGroup'
    || prop === 'productName'
    || prop === 'color'
    || prop === 'configuration')
```

because Xcode handles it well, and because you can delete every line easily. First and last line ar slightly trickier.

Comment: Every except first and last

Comment: This is exactly the point though, I'm trying to get rid of the little hassle of first and /or last line replacements.

Comment: First and last line are only a _tiny_ bit more difficult: Instead of selecting a whole line  you select for example from just before the first "prop" to just before the second "prop".